# Cannot stop Gulp with Ctrl+C when using gulp-nodemon & gulp.watch together

Tags: javascript, gulp

When I run gulp without the `node` task, it works fine and processes client file as expected, If I run `gulp node` it processes server file as expected. However if I run both `gulp` it processes both client and server file as expected, however, it won't let me quit by pressing 'Ctrl + C' (Tried it on windows 10 & Mac El Capitan). Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
'use strict';
  var gulp = require('gulp');
    var connect = require('gulp-connect'); 
    var browserify = require('browserify'); 
    var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); 
    var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

    var config = {
        port: 9005,
        devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
        paths: {
            html: './src/*.html',
            dist: './dist',
            js: './src/**/*.js',
            images: './src/images/*',
            mainJs: './src/main.js',
            css: [
                'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
            ]
        }
    };

gulp.task('connect', function () {
    connect.server({
        root: ['dist'],
        port: config.port,
        base: config.devBaseUrl,
        livereload: true
    });
});


gulp.task('html', function () {
    gulp.src(config.paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
    browserify(config.paths.mainJs)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/scripts'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())

});

gulp.task('node', function () {
    nodemon({
        script: 'server/index.js',
        ext: 'js',
        env: {
            PORT: 8000
        },
        ignore: ['node_modules/**','src/**','dist/**']
    })
    .on('restart', function () {
        console.log('Restarting node server...');
    })
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'js', 'connect', 'node', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Can you get this down to the smallest amount of code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I've removed the part that was unnecessary

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue before this is what you're looking for :

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('Successfully closed ' + process.pid));
    process.exit(1);
  }, 500);
});
```

Just add this code to your gulp file. It will watch the ctrl + C and properly terminate the process. You can put some other code in the timeout also if desired.

Answer (score 3):

Right at the top you have

```
var monitorCtrlC = require('monitorctrlc');
```

and inside of the `watch` task you have

```
monitorCtrlC();
```

Which seems to be [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monitorctrlc)

> This function will prevent sending of SIGINT signal when Ctrl+C is
>   pressed. Instead, the specified (or default) callback will be invoked.

Comment: That's something I use just when I'm developing on windows. Since on windows it requires pressing 'Ctrl + C' first and then confirming 'YES/NO' to end batch process, monitorCtrlC() just helps remove extra step in windows. However I've already tried removing it completely since I don't need it on the Mac, the end result was still the same.

Comment: You probably shouldn't include it in this question then since it does exactly what you're complaining about :)

Comment: sorry, I've remove it to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

The SIGINT solution did not work for me, probably because I'm also using gulp-nodemon but this worked:

```
    var monitor = $.nodemon(...)
    // Make sure we can exit on Ctrl+C
    process.once('SIGINT', function() {
    monitor.once('exit', function() {
          console.log('Closing gulp');
          process.exit();
        });
    });
    monitor.once('quit', function() {
        console.log('Closing gulp');
        process.exit();
    });
```

Got it from [here](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon/issues/83).

Answer (score 0):

just in case it helps someone else, I deleted the `node_modules` and did `npm install` which fixed the issue for me...