# Can't stop gulp with CTRL+C

Tags: javascript, macos, gulp

I am running a project with gulp and I get this in the terminal:

```
crsjopgp6444:promo-llove-your-app-2 berretan$ gulp
[14:14:39] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Projects/promo-llove-your-app-2/gulpfile.js
[14:14:39] Starting 'assemble'...
[14:14:39] Starting 'sass'...
[14:14:40] Starting 'fonts'...
[14:14:40] Starting 'notify:server'...
[14:14:40] Finished 'fonts' after 197 ms
[14:14:41] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Server ready!
[14:14:41] Finished 'notify:server' after 244 ms
[14:14:41] Finished 'assemble' after 2.04 s
```

when I try to stop the project with CTRL+C isn't allowing me, it's just don't do anything, I have to close the tab and open it in a new one.

And in the browser I can't see anything in the port 9000 which is the one I chose, all I see is this:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
>
> Search Google for localhost 9000

I am using El Capitan with Node 5.5.0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add your gulp configuration? If you can not stop a bash process with CTRL+C this means that you computer can not stop a running process properly. This can be caused by a lot of things/taks :-/

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer what about Ctrl + D ?????

Answer (score 1):

Although an old question, it still pops up in Google. Here is what ultimately worked for me when using nodemon:

```
var monitor = $.nodemon(...)
// Make sure we can exit on Ctrl+C
process.once('SIGINT', function() {
monitor.once('exit', function() {
      console.log('Closing gulp');
      process.exit();
    });
});
monitor.once('quit', function() {
    console.log('Closing gulp');
    process.exit();
});
```

Got it from [here](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon/issues/83).

If you are not using nodemon, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953294/cannot-stop-gulp-with-ctrlc-when-using-gulp-nodemon-gulp-watch-together/51431548#51431548) might work as well:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    process.exit(1);
  }, 500);
});
```